tcblistof issue with macro inside tcolorbox title
I write a lot of reports (minutes). Each report can contains a lot of subjects.
For a better tracking, each subjet is attached with a unique persisent number.
I managed to do so thanks to this subject :
persistent counters between builds
Each subject is in tcolorbox. The macro for writing persistent number works correctly.
Now I want to create a list of all subject at the beginning of the report.
I add the \tcblistof[] command. I now have an error when compiling.
When I remove the macro from the tcolorbox environment, it compiles well and the list of subject is correctly written.
Here is the MWE : (if you compile it with Overleaf, don’t forget to add a stored.txt file)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title{CR test}

\date{June 2024}

%--------- macro for printing persistent numbers -----------

\newcommand{\persistent}{} % create initially empty list

\newcounter{Current}       % existing position in list
\newcounter{MaxSeq}        % highest position in list
\newtoggle{FoundInList}    % boolean test if item is found

\newcommand{\cmphandler}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{Current}%      % increase position in list
    \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}%        % if the current item is the item to print
    {\toggletrue{FoundInList}\listbreak}{}%    % then set to found and exit loop
}

% write full list to file after adding items 
\newcommand{\writeall}[1]{\write\listfile{\noexpand\listgadd{\noexpand\persistent}{#1}\noexpand\stepcounter{MaxSeq}}}

% print the current item in the document
\newcommand{\printpersistent}[1]{%
\setcounter{Current}{0}%
\togglefalse{FoundInList}%
\forlistloop{\cmphandler{#1}}{\persistent}% % find position in list
\iftoggle{FoundInList}%                     % if item is found
{\arabic{Current} #1}%                      % print position and item
{\listgadd{\persistent}{#1}\stepcounter{MaxSeq}\arabic{MaxSeq} #1}%     % else add to end of list and print item
%\par                                        % start new paragraph
}


%------ custom tcolorbox----------

\newtcolorbox[list inside=listpoint]{point}[3][]{title={\printpersistent{#2}},#1,
after title={\hfill #3},
colback=white,
colframe=gray!20,
boxrule=0.4pt,
colbacktitle=gray!20,
coltitle=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,
colback=gray!5,
colupper=black,
before upper={$\rightarrow$~}},
arc=1pt,}

%------------------------------------

\begin{document}

% load existing list if available
\InputIfFileExists{stored.txt}{}{}

% print full list to file
\newwrite\listfile
\openout\listfile=stored.txt
\forlistloop{\writeall}{\persistent}
\closeout\listfile

%----------List of all subjects---------

\tcblistof[\section*]{listpoint}{Subjects list}

%--------- All subjects-----------------

\section{Subjects}

\begin{point}{Introduction}{27/06/2024}
Entity
\tcblower
Main subject
\tcbsubtitle{update 5/07/24}
Updated subject
\end{point}

\end{document}

Thanks for your help.
